# How can i wait until the data is written to file?

Tags: android, camera

I want take picture from camera, save to file and upload to server. I use follow code:

```
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, 
                           Uri.fromFile(mCurrentPhotoFile));
startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, RESULT_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

and

```
 if (requestCode == RESULT_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && mCurrentPhotoFile != null) {
     uploadFile(mCurrentPhotoFile);
 }
```

But sometimes file has 0 bytes size. I think it's because picture don't save immediately and i need wait for saving finish.

How i can fix it?

Comment: Did you solve your issue ? please share with us if yes

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait till image is save in gallery. After you can upload image to server.

So below class is for getting image after saved in gallery.

```
public class SingleMediaScanner implements MediaScannerConnection.MediaScannerConnectionClient {

    private MediaScannerConnection mMs;
    private File mFile;

    public SingleMediaScanner(Context context, File f) {
        mFile = f;
        mMs = new MediaScannerConnection(context, this);
        mMs.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMediaScannerConnected() {
        mMs.scanFile(mFile.getAbsolutePath(), null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
        mMs.disconnect();

        System.out.println("path......"+path);
        System.out.println("uri......"+uri);

        // here you can upload image to server
        uploadFile(mCurrentPhotoFile);
    }
}
```

To execute above class just call constructor

```
new SingleMediaScanner(this, imageFile);
```

Comment: it's don't work :( I tried add image file to gallery after creation but also don't work :(

Comment: @actin it will work if you are creating imgFile object.